# Entity framework code first many-to-many relationshiop initialization

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

In the following [Entity framework official example](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx).

1. Why the initialization of `Students` exists in the constructor of `Course` only (`this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();`)? Why not in the constructor of `Student`?
2. Is the initialization necessary? I used to implement one-to-many relationship and I didn't initial the virtual `List<...>` and the program works fine. (Is it because I used `List<...>` instead of `ICollection<...>`?

**code:**

```
public class Student
{
    public Student() { }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public int StdandardId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
    }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no need to initialize it, because it is marked as `virtual` and will be lazy-loaded on demand. However, if they tried to insert new items into the `Students` collection, this initialization would matter - because it prevents `NullReferenceException`
2. You really should use `ICollection` instead of a `List` - in 99% cases `ICollection` contract is enough and using an interface instead of a class makes you design more flexible (for example you can use HashSet and not the List)